# Render too dark

Tags: rendering, light

After deleting an old render image from the Video Sequence Editor, which was preventing me from seeing anything when rendering, I've noticed that renders are too dark now. My light is enabled and in the scene, the settings are the same as in another model, and I've tried deleting the light and creating a new one.

Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide the old file with the old render img in it?.
As I look it the problem may be the world color, right now is HEX 404040 (pretty dark).

Comment: Sure. Here we are: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5643" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5643/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, you need to enable the scene layer like in the image, the problem was, that the layer where the sun is, is not enabled for rendering.

[image]

Comment: Oh. Would have thought that was already enabled. Not sure how that happened. Thank you. :)

Comment: How are you supposed to tell which of those layers is what?